# load CCSprite from sdcard

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

I normally load my spritesheet bundled with my app this way:

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile( "myspritesheet.plist");
CCSprite *pSprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrame( CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName("sprite_monster.png");
pSprite->setPosition(ccp(100.0f,100.0f));
this->addChild(pSprite);
```

However, as the number of textures are growing and to accomodate easier updates, I am planning to place some of the spritesheets to the server and download it to the sdcard (or Cache folder in iOS). However, I don't see ways of loading it in game.

This link show how to load the png texture. But if I have multiple sprite packed into a single texture, I'll need to load the .plist file and feed it into CCSpriteFrameCache. Anybody knows how to do that? or any other solution how to load the individual CCSprite from the texture that has multiple sprites?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("myspritesheet.png");
this->addChild(batchNode);
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("myspritesheet.plist");

CCSprite *pSprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("sprite_monster.png");
pSprite->setPosition(ccp(100.0f,100.0f));
this->addChild(pSprite);
```